# JS - How to securely use window.postMessage when the sender domain is unknown

Tags: javascript, security, web, cross-domain, postmessage

I would like to create a secure postMessage connection (origin safe), with an Iframe that is created at runtime.

**Current state:**
I have a script, that generates an iframe with a specific domain (`domain.b.com` in the example below). I want that iframe to receive messages only from the parent domain (the page that included my script). Since the parent domain is unknown at runtime, I'm thinking of a "Handshake" process as described and illustrated below:

1. Wait for Iframe to be loaded.
2. Send postMessage from the parent domain with it's origin.
3. Set the allowed origin to be the 1st received origin

**Edit:**
More Info:

1. On my server I have a whitelist domains (for example domain.a.com, any.domain.com, domain.b.com)
2. My Goal is to integrate with some of my clients (for example domain.a.com , domain.b.com)
3. Once integrated I want to prevent hackers injecting Iframes that can listen to sensitive information over postMessage
4. I want to avoid checking the whitelist, I prefer to give some acessToken, but not sure what is the right flow.

**Example 1:**

[image]

---

**Example 2:**

[image]

Is that the right way to implement it?

Comment: I believe you've made a mistake in your second example. I think wanted to say `postMessage("any.domain.com", "domain.b.com")` in your first postMessage!

Comment: You are right ... sorry for that

Comment: Is there a reason why you don’t just provide the parent domain in the URL loaded within the iframe (`<iframe src="http://b.example?source=a.example></iframe>`)? The code in the iframe could then extract that information from its `window.location.search` to decide which is the correct safe source domain.

Comment: I like your idea, but not sure it is hacker free.

Comment: I'm confused! Are you developing the main window's code or the iframe's?

Comment: The iframe is generated via Script that is included in the Main page, I'm writing the Script and the Iframe content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage#Security_concerns), you should not expect the parent's origin to be sent to you in `postMessage`'s parameter. Instead:

> If you do expect to receive messages from other sites, always verify
>   the sender's identity using the **origin** and possibly **source** properties.
>   Any window (including, for example, http://evil.example.com) can send
>   a message to any other window, and you have no guarantees that an
>   unknown sender will not send malicious messages. Having verified
>   identity, however, you still should always verify the syntax of the
>   received message. Otherwise, a security hole in the site you trusted
>   to send only trusted messages could then open a cross-site scripting
>   hole in your site.

And once you have the main frame's URI in your iframe, you can verify its authorization with a simple AJAX call to the server. In my point of view, a server call is inevitable and one way or another you will make such a call.

There are other ways to know who is including your iframe but they are not relying on `postMessage`. For instance if you are using PHP, you can check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to see who is requesting your iframe even before it is sent to the browser. Yet there are ways to [referrer spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing) as well.

If your application requires a solid bullet proof solution then server to server communication is your way. In this scenario, each client of yours has a username and password and the web server who is going to serve the main page should ask for a one time pass token from the web server who is serving the iframe (this is a server to server communication). And then use the token in the iframe's URL to be sent back to the server generated it. Here's a step by step of this scenario:

1. End user asks for the URL `http://customer.com/main.php`.
2. While `main.php` is executing and populating the response, it also
   connects to
   `http://you_website.com/generate_token.php?username=cutomer1&password=123`
   and gets a one time pass token `token1`.
3. The response is returned to the browser containing an iframe with URL `http://your_website.com/iframe.php?token=token1`.
4. In `iframe.php` you verify the `token1` to see if it is valid, and
   , at the same time, you are authenticating the requester without actually asking
   for his username and/or password (since you know who you have
   generated the token for).

Such tokens are usually deleted once used (one time pass) and they also usually come with an expiration data. But that's up to you and your application.

Comment: That is exactly my question, how can you verify the sender identity if the sender is different for each site that included the script?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly! Once you have an incoming event on your message event handler, you also have its sender's `URI` which is given to you by browser so you can always be sure that it is the truth. And now that you have the sender's `URI` you can check it with any trust worthy source you might have to test and see if the origin is within your white list or not. Let me know if I'm misunderstood.

Comment: I want to avoid white listing ... instead I'm thinking of something like a token, but since it is only client side, I'm not sure that is the solution. Your thought?

Comment: Then I must say you needed to mention that in your question. So is it that you want to avoid any server communication within your iframe or you just want to avoid white listing? What is your criteria to allow or prevent one site from using your iframe? Can any website include your iframe? The answers to these questions are the key to your solution. And bear in mind that I'm not talking about the implementation of how to decide which origin to allow but the concept on what's the decisive criteria.

Comment: Thank you for your well explained answer, However , I was thinking of something like what Facebook does with applications. (posting a signed_request -> decoding in server side -> passing result to the frame).

Comment: Sorry I have not studied Facebook's technology and I really would like to know what they do. Even though it might be easier and less expensive to implement than the solution I explained but I hardly doubt that it's safer.

Comment: I guess you are right, I'll post if I have a different solution :)